# How to check if a URL exists

Tags: http, python-3.7

I'm working with python 3.7 and OS - Windows 10 pro.

I have URLs like:

```
http://example.com/[text, image, table]/[0001-8000].pdf
```

I'm trying to form a table which would look like

1 - Text
2 - Image
3 - Text
4 - Table
5 - Image

etc.

I've tried using http.client, urlopen from urllib.request, requests etc. All are either getting timed out or giving nonnumeric port error.

One example:

```
import requests  

baseURL = 'http://example.com/'  
type = ['text', 'image', 'table']  
for fN in range (8000):  
    for tp in type:  
        workURL = baseURL + tp + '/' + str(fN + 1).zfill(4) + '.pdf'  
        if requests.head(workURL, timeout = 0.0001).status_code == 200:  
            "write fN + 1 and tp values to a csv file before proceeding to the next loop with next fN."  
            break
```

No output. Simply 'hangs' at `if requests.head(workURL, timeout = 0.0001).status_code == 200:`

Comment: Try quoting `baseURL`.

Comment: Same results! Actually I already quoted the 'baseURL' initially while running the code.